# Matplotlib: getting tick label properties (e.g. font size)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given an axes object in matplotlib, I want to find properties of tick labels, such as font size, rotation, etc.

Why do I want to do this? Because I an trying to write a function that adds some text to a plot, and I want the text to look the same as the (y) axis tick labels by default.

I googled and found lots of explanations about how to set tick label properties, but not how to retrieve these properties from the axes.

EDIT: `Axes.get_xticklabels` works in most cases, but of course it breaks if there are currently no ticks, which is rare, but still, this is not ideal. It seems that there is a property on the `Axes` object itself, not just the `Text` objects returned by this function. Consider:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels() # this returns []

ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=25)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([0.5])
```

After running this code, the tick label "0.5" shows up in 25 point font, which means that the 25 is stored somewhere by the axes and not just in the text objects.

Comment: [`Axes.get_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels.html)?

Comment: That gets me a list of Text objects, on which I can then call get_fontsize() on so I suppose that works, but I feel like there should be a property on the axes object that i should be able to get at.

Comment: @mrip I think that's correct -- and since you can change the properties of individual tick labels I'm not sure how much good an axes property would do (what should it return?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to get the properties from the individual [`matplotlib.text.Text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) objects that make up the ticklabels.

For example, if you know they're all the same:

```
xta = ax.get_xticklabels()
xtext = xta[0]
print(xtext.get_font())                 # sans\-serif:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=10.0
print(xtext.get_fontfamily())           # ['sans-serif']
print(xtext.get_fontsize())             # 10.0
print(xtext.get_rotation())             # 0.0
print(xtext.get_rotation_mode())        # None
```

The getters are listed in the linked docs or can be found buried in `print(dir(xtext))`

Comment: This works unless there are currently no ticks; see my edit.

Comment: @mrip If you're okay with accessing "private" internals: `ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=25); print(ax.yaxis._major_tick_kw)` -> `{..., 'labelsize': 25}`

Comment: Thanks, helpful. But, by default 'labelsize' is not part of that dict, which means again there's a scenario where if I want to automate this, I might not be able to find a value and get an error. Is the default labelsize hard-coded somewhere inside a function that can't be accessed from the outside? Maybe this is as close as I'm going to get...

Comment: @mrip `labelsize` will be part of that dict if it's set (e.g. the `.tick_params(..., labelsize=<whatever>)`.  If it's _not_ explicitly set, afaict mpl will fall back to the value in rcparams "dict" (not _really_ a dict, but it doesn't matter)(and this should always be set): `print(mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'])` -> `'medium'`  So it seems like you'd want to (1) check the ticks first (to see if they've been set individually), (2) check the `tick_params` of the axes, (3) finally, fallback to the value from `rcParams`

Comment: Yes, thanks again. It just feels wrong lol. I mean, when the Axes object needs to draw a new axis label, somewhere it runs some code that figures out what the size should be. And I feel like I should be able to access this value by calling say `ax.yaxis.what_size_should_i_make_the_label()` rather than re-writing the function myself.  Still, appreciate all your help.

Comment: Because, truthfully, I don't think that being able to draw new text on a plot that matches the style of the current axis label is such an extravagant demand. In my particular use case, I want to annotate a bar chart by writing values of some of the bars right above the bar, and I want the annotated values to have the same format, size, font, etc as the y-axis labels. I don't feel like I should have to jump through hoops.